# Add Email Body to Attachment with Email Service

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have to do a email service that when I send a mail to my salesforce email service, it creates a contact with the first and lastname of the people who send, and attach the email to the contact created. I have the following code where I can save an attachment file, but I want to modify it to save the email body content:

```
global class OrbC_AttachEmailDossier implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.FirstName = email.fromname.substring(0,email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
    contact.LastName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
    contact.Email = envelope.fromAddress;
    insert contact;

    System.debug('====> Created contact '+contact.Id);

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ParentId = contact.Id;
    attachment.Name = email.subject;
    attachment.Body = email.HtmlBody;
    insert attachment;

    return result;

  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

> Illegal assignment from String to Blob

When I try to associate the `email.htmlBody` to `attachment.Body` . What I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says you are trying to assign a String value (`email.HtmlBody`) to a Blob type field/variable (`attachment.Body`).

You can convert the String into a Blob and then assign it.

```
attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(email.HtmlBody);
```

OR

you can follow the examples in this [developer force reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) and  create a note from the email text body

```
Note note = new Note();    
note.Title = email.fromName + ' (' + DateTime.now() + ')';
note.Body = email.plainTextBody;
note.ParentId = account.Id;
insert note;
```